# Create new Changelist Perforce Java API

Tags: java, perforce, changelist

I am trying to write a method to create a new change list in perforce using the p4java api. I am able to connect to the server, get an IFileSpec list, sync files and check if files/folders exist.

However, I am unable to create a new change list. I tried the method on [this](http://kb.perforce.com/article/1342/common-usage-patterns-for-p4java) page with no luck... If anybody has an example they could share I would appreciate it!

The part of code failing me is,

```
167: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class OptionsServer
location: class tools.test.PerforceSyncer
                    (OptionsServer)iServer
```

Comment: Please add details of how the example code failed for you.

Comment: Just added compilation error there.. hope it helps

Comment: Looks like a typo in that KB article. That constructor appears to take a boolean as the 7th argument: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4java-javadoc/com/perforce/p4java/impl/generic/core/Changelist.html#Changelist(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, com.perforce.p4java.core.ChangelistStatus, java.util.Date, java.lang.String, boolean, com.perforce.p4java.impl.mapbased.server.Server)

Comment: The problem turned out to be that instead of (OptionsServer)iServer, it should have been (Server)iServer. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was that instead of

```
Changelist changeListImpl = new Changelist(
        IChangelist.UNKNOWN,
        iClient.getName(),
        "tom",
        ChangelistStatus.NEW,
        new Date(),
        "New changelist",
        false,
   ---->(OptionsServer)iServer
        );
```

Should have been

```
 Changelist changeListImpl = new Changelist(
        IChangelist.UNKNOWN,
        iClient.getName(),
        "tom",
        ChangelistStatus.NEW,
        new Date(),
        "New changelist",
        false,
   ---->(Server)iServer
        );
```